# Invalid keystore format Visual Studio 2019

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

When I try to build my Xamarin.Android project, I get error:

> MSB6006: "java.exe" exited with code 2

In the output I see:

C:\Program Files\Eclipse Foundation\jdk-8.0.302.8-hotspot\bin\java.exe -jar "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\apksigner.jar" sign --ks "C:\Users\drake\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Mono for Android\debug.keystore" --ks-pass pass:android --ks-key-alias androiddebugkey --key-pass pass:android --min-sdk-version 22 --max-sdk-version 27  C:\Users\drake\source\repos\myapp\myapp\myapp.Android\bin\Debug\com.xamarin.drake.myapp-Signed.apk
Failed to load signer "signer #1"
java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format

Comment: Did you try to delete the existed key and create a new one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by deleting the existing debug.keystore file from "C:\Users\YourUser\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Mono for Android"